# How can I instantiate programaticaly an application with scim enabled into Azure

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm writing a test that instantiate an application and I want to create a synchronization job but I have a problem with the Graph API, when I call this endpoints :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationtemplate-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I have this error :

```
{'error': {'code': 'UnknownError',  'innerError': {'date': '2020-06-22T19:35:22', 'request-id': 'e1de2a7f-f0a1-49e0-a183-db863c4e3eaf'},  'message': ''}}
```

Like it says, ‘unknown Error' is difficult to resolve.

I have set the permission : Directory.ReadWrite.All Delegated

The status code returned was 500.

The purpose : create an app for each test BDD and test the synchronization with SCIM.

Comment: Please share your full request.

Comment: the request is generated with Python : url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{service_id}/synchronization/templates"
r = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + self.access_token})

Answer (score 0):

Currently delegated permission is only available for SCIM using Microsoft graph.

Please refer the permission information in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationtemplate-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).